# Fill the column using the previous value in the column and some calculations in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

My dataframe looks like this:

```
   scale  cons    hold    supply   add.supply     s_res      z_res
48  -5     NaN    NaN      NaN       NaN           NaN        NaN   
49  -4     NaN    NaN      NaN       NaN           NaN        NaN   
50  -3     NaN    NaN      NaN       NaN           NaN        NaN   
51  -2     NaN    NaN      NaN       NaN           NaN        NaN   
52  -1     NaN    NaN      NaN       NaN           NaN        NaN   
53   0      0     300       0        NaN           100        200   
54   1     20     NaN       0        NaN           200        322   
55   2     30     NaN      70        NaN           100        100   
56   3     25     NaN       0        NaN           400        110   
57   4     15     NaN       0        NaN           100        300   
58   5     10     NaN       0        NaN           100        180   
59   6     40     NaN       0        NaN           100        100   
...
```

I need to do the following:

Starting with the value where `scale = 1` fill the column `hold` with values calculated as follows:

I take the previous value in the column `hold` and subtract from it the corresponding value of the current cell from the column `cons` and add the corresponding value from the column `supply`.

(For a cell in a column `hold` that corresponds to `scale = 1` it will be `(300 - 20) + 0 = 280`,
for the next cell `(280 - 30) + 70) = 320`, for the next cell `(320 - 25) + 0) = 295` and so on)

If the value in the column `hold` is less than the corresponding value in the column `s_res`, then to the next cell I must add the difference between the corresponding next cell values in the columns `s_res` and `z_res`.

For example, the value in the column `hold` is `295`, where `scale = 3`. This value is less than the value in the column `s_res = 400`. Then the next value I need to count so: `(295 - 15) + 0 + (300 - 100) = 480`. And write this difference between `s_res` and `z_res` in the column `add.supply`.

I need every new calculated value in the column `hold` check whether it is less than the value in the column `s_res`.

The result should look like this:

```
   scale  cons    hold    supply   add.supply     s_res      z_res
48  -5     NaN    NaN      NaN       NaN           NaN        NaN   
49  -4     NaN    NaN      NaN       NaN           NaN        NaN   
50  -3     NaN    NaN      NaN       NaN           NaN        NaN   
51  -2     NaN    NaN      NaN       NaN           NaN        NaN   
52  -1     NaN    NaN      NaN       NaN           NaN        NaN   
53   0      0     300       0        NaN           100        200   
54   1     20     280       0        NaN           200        322   
55   2     30     320      70        NaN           100        100   
56   3     25     295       0        NaN           400        110   
57   4     15     480       0        200           100        300   
58   5     10     470       0        NaN           100        180   
59   6     40     430       0        NaN           100        100   
...
```

I would be grateful for any advice.

**UPD** I tried to apply the code

```
df['hold'] = df.hold.fillna(method='ffill') - df.cons.cumsum() + df.supply.cumsum()
df['add.supply'] = np.where(df.hold.shift() < df.s_res.shift(), df.z_res - df.s_res, np.nan)
df['hold'] = df.hold + df['add.supply'].fillna(0).cumsum()
```

to a larger dataframe and I'm having problems

My new dataframe

```
   scale   cons   hold  supply  add.supply   s_res   z_res
 0   0       0    300     0        NaN        100     200
 1   1      20    NaN     0        NaN        200     322
 2   2      30    NaN    70        NaN        100     100
 3   3      25    NaN     0        NaN        400     110
 4   4      15    NaN     0        NaN        100     300
 5   5      10    NaN     0        NaN        100     180
 6   6      40    NaN     0        NaN        100     100
 7   7      60    NaN     0        NaN        300     400
 8   8      50    NaN     0        NaN        245     300
 9   9      70    NaN     0        NaN        300     600
10  10      50    NaN     0        NaN        143     228
...
```

The result should be the following:

```
   scale   cons   hold  supply  add.supply   s_res   z_res
 0   0       0    300     0        NaN        100     200
 1   1      20    280     0        NaN        200     322
 2   2      30    320    70        NaN        100     100
 3   3      25    295     0        NaN        400     110
 4   4      15    480     0        200        100     300
 5   5      10    470     0        NaN        100     180
 6   6      40    430     0        NaN        100     100
 7   7      60    370     0        NaN        300     400
 8   8      50    320     0        NaN        245     300
 9   9      70    250     0        NaN        300     600
10  10      50    285     0         85        143     228
...
```

But the result of the code execution was not what it should be:

```
   scale   cons   hold  supply  add.supply   s_res   z_res
 0   0       0    300     0        NaN        100     200
 1   1      20    280     0        NaN        200     322
 2   2      30    320    70        NaN        100     100
 3   3      25    295     0        NaN        400     110
 4   4      15    480     0        200        100     300
 5   5      10    470     0        NaN        100     180
 6   6      40    430     0        NaN        100     100
 7   7      60    370     0        NaN        300     400
 8   8      50    375     0         55        245     300
 9   9      70    605     0        300        300     600
10  10      50    640     0         85        143     228
...
```

Error appears after `hold = 370`, but I don't understand why.

Comment: Can you explain what you've tried to do so far?  That can help people find what they can most usefully explain.

Comment: @ASGM I apologize, but I'm afraid I did not fully understand your question. However, the very beginning of the task causes the greatest difficulties. I don't understand how to use the previous value in the column `hold` and at the same time subtract from it the value in the column `cons` corresponding to the cell for which I am currently calculating. In any case, the calculation will always start from the place where the `scale = 1`. I tried to use `shift()`, but I didn't succeed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of doing this row by row, you can use a combination of [`cumsum()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.cumsum.html) and [`np.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) to do this across the whole DataFrame:

```
df['hold'] = df.hold.fillna(method='ffill') - df.cons.cumsum() + df.supply.cumsum()
df['add.supply'] = np.where(df.hold.shift() < df.s_res.shift(), df.z_res - df.s_res, np.nan)
df['hold'] = df.hold + df['add.supply'].fillna(0).cumsum()
```

Think of the transformations you want to do in two stages.  You have an initial stage where you're adding and subtracting from an initial value of `df.hold`.  Then you're altering that new value of hold in some cases, according to some conditions.

`cumsum()` takes a Series or DataFrame and makes a new version where each row is the cumulative sum of the previous rows and the current row.  You can do that for `df.cons` and `df.supply` to get the cumulative amounts that will be subtracted from and added to `df.hold`.  Now you have the first stage of `df.hold` calculated.

You can use `np.where` to find out when `df.hold` meets the conditions you're interested in.  Where it does, you can set `df['add.supply']` accordingly.  Then you can add this new column to `df.hold`.  Note that we're using `fillna(0)` to make sure each row has a value, and `cumsum()` again to preserve the added conditional values over time.

**UPDATE**

The original code above didn't work after the addition of one value of `add.supply`, because future values of the first stage of `df.hold` didn't include it yet.  There may be a way to do this non-iteratively, and there's certainly a better and cleaner way than what I've done below, but this at least will get the job done:

```
df['hold'] = df.hold.fillna(method='ffill') - df.cons.cumsum() + df.supply.cumsum()

hold = df.hold.tolist()
s_res = df.s_res.tolist()
add = (df.z_res - df.s_res).shift(-1).tolist()

newh = [hold[0]]
totala = 0
for h, s, a in zip(hold, s_res, add):
    newh.append(h + totala)
    if newh[-1] < s:
        totala += a

df['hold'] = pd.Series(newh[1:])
df['add.supply'] = np.where(df.hold.shift() < df.s_res.shift(), df.z_res - df.s_res, np.nan)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Could you please look at the update in question? I'm having problems with the result.

Comment: @YanaDolyuk I see the problem, and I'm figuring out something to fix it.

Comment: @YanaDolyuk I've provided a quick and dirty solution to the problem.  I'm sure there's a better way to do it - but this will get the job done.  Maybe you can clean it up!

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much!